# Doctrine database creation using zend in MAC?

Tags: macos, unix, doctrine-orm, terminal, zend-framework2

i’m using zend in mac and i’m trying to create a database using the command

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

but i get the ERROR :

```
line 7: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module: Permission denied
```

can anyone help please ??
 **EDIT**
this is the line 7 in `doctrine-module` script

```
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@«
```

it’s where i get the permission denied ERROR

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to invoke the doctrine module command line directly. You can access all it's commands from the normal public/index.php CLI.

For example:

```
php public/index.php orm:schema-tool:create
```

Comment: i got this message: `Zend Framework 2.2.5 application
Usage:

Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided`

Comment: @Tomdarkness are you sure? The zend index?